# childNodes.length 0 in Chrome / Correct In IE & FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a div with children that I need to crawl looking for specific links. The HTML looks like so:

```
<div id="ctl00_LeftNav">
    <h3>
        <a href="../App_Templates/#" rel="0">Menu 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            <span>
                <div style="padding-left: 0px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <a href="javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(1);">Opt 1</a></div>
                <div style="padding-left: 10px;">
                    <a href="javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(56);">Opt 1a</a></div>
                <div style="padding-left: 0px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <a href="javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(2);">Opt 2</a></div>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="../App_Templates/#" rel="1">Menu 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            <span>
                <div style="padding-left: 0px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <a href="javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(33);">Opt 1</a></div>
                <div style="padding-left: 0px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <a href="javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(34);">Opt 2</a></div>
                <div style="padding-left: 10px;">
                    <a href="javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(42);">Opt 2a</a></div>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="../App_Templates/#" rel="2">Menu 3</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            <span>
                <div style="padding-left: 0px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <a href="javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(58);">Opt 1</a></div>
                <div style="padding-left: 0px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <a href="javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(59);">Opt 2</a></div>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript that I have works fine in IE / Firefox, but fails in Chrome:

```
        function OnPageLoadCategorySelect(Category) {            
        var Root = $j('#ctl00_LeftNav').children();
        var Tab = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < Root.length; i += 2) {
            var Menu = Root[i].firstChild.firstChild.childNodes;                
            var MenuLength = Menu.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < Menu.length; j++) {
                var Link = Menu[j].innerHTML;
                var Start = Link.indexOf('(');
                var End = Link.indexOf(')');
                var Res = Link.slice(Start + 1, End);
                if (Res == Category) {
                    SelectedTabIndex = Tab;                        
                    OnLeftMenuSelection(Category);
                    $j('#ShopTabs').show();
                    $j('#ctl00_LeftNav').accordion('activate', Tab);                      
                    return;
                }
            }                
            Tab++;                
        }
    }
```

In Chrome the 2nd for loop never executes because Menu.length is zero. What would be the best way to get these internal divs?

*Solution*

```
function OnPageLoadCategorySelect(Category) {
$j("#ctl00_LeftNav > div").each(function(Tab, el) {
            $j('a', this).each(function() {
                var id = $j(this).attr('href').replace('javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(', '').replace(');', '');
                if (id == Category) {
                    SelectedTabIndex = Tab;
                    OnLeftMenuSelection(Category);
                    $j('#ShopTabs').show();
                    $j('#ctl00_LeftNav').accordion('activate', Tab);
                    return false; // exit the loop
                }
            })
        });
 }
```

Comment: Kinda - I'm learning jQuery. So if there is a better way using that let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, replace your whole function with this:

```
function OnPageLoadCategorySelect(Category) {
  $j("#ctl00_LeftNav > div").each(function(Tab, el){
      $j('a', this).each(function(){
          var id = $j(this).attr('href').replace('javascript:OnLeftMenuSelection(','').replace(')','');
          if( id == Category ) {
              SelectedTabIndex = Tab;                        
              OnLeftMenuSelection(Category);
              $j('#ShopTabs').show();
              $j('#ctl00_LeftNav').accordion('activate', Tab);                      
              return false; // exit the loop
          }
      })
  });
}
```

The first parameter of the `each` function is the zero based index. By supplying Tab, it counts it up for you.

Comment: Wow, thanks Doug. Just started writing my own, but this I'll try this when mine fails....

Comment: Didnt work. When I step through it with firebug it just skips right over the '$j("#ctl00_LeftNav > div").each(function(Tab, el)'.

Comment: @Chris, the selector I provided would work for the HTML you provided. Chances are, the ID has changed, or the HTML is not the same (meaning, the `div` is not a direct child of the `#ctl00...`). If you view the source of the page (**not** Firebug source), is it the same as you posted above?

Comment: @Chris - In addition to Doug's suggestion, have you made a call to `jQuery.noConflict()` before using the '$j' alias?

Comment: Got it. Yep its the same - the id was taking the ending ';'. Just replaced **.replace(')','');** with **.replace(');','');**. It works!

Comment: And in Chrome. Have to try Safari later - but looks great.

Comment: @Doug - Out of curiosity, why the nested `each()` instead of utilizing jQuery's selector features? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @patrick Only because he needed a index counter of `Tab`. I could have just searched the `a` elements, then used a combination of `closest('#ctl_000LeftNav > div')` and `index()` but this seemed more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using jQuery.

```
$('#ctl00_LeftNav').children("div").each(function(index) {

   alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text()); // displays inner text of div

});
```

or this gets all children divs of the selector as pointed out by patrick

```
$('#ctl00_LeftNav > div').each(function(index) {

   alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text()); // displays inner text of div

});
```

Source: [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for loops

Comment: Is there any way to just grab the div's and not the h3 tags? How would I do the internal loop?

Comment: I updated my answer so it grabs all children divs of the selector.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty simple. Thanks - going to give it a shot now.

Comment: This code would only look for divs that are **immediate children** of `#ctl00_LeftNav`. It would not traverse deeper descendants.

Comment: @patrick, yes i know. I gave him the basic idea where he should be able to get all the children he needs by using the basic idea of this.

Comment: Yea, it got me off to the right start. Just nested the .each's. Going to test it in all the browsers soon.

Comment: @gmcalab - Unfortunately, your second solution does the exact same as the first. Using `>` limits the selection to **immediate children**. `$('#ctl00_LeftNav > div')` selects immediate child divs, `$('#ctl00_LeftNav  div')` selects **all** child divs. *Without additional code like Doug Neiner offered, it would never select the desired divs.*